# Grayscale and opacity in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, opacity, grayscale

I am using the following for grayscale in firefox:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
```

However, when using this, setting Opacity doesn't work. How can I use both?

Comment: [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3grd0oa/) shows both greyscale and opacity working together.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) with multiple effects:

```css
div{ filter: grayscale(75%) opacity(75%); /*opacity:0.75;*/ }
div:hover{ filter: none; }
```

```html
<div style="width:64px;height:64px;background-color:#F0F;"></div>
```

It’s [standard compliant](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty) (SVG) and has decent [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter). It runs smoothly in Firefox (as asked for). Chrome requires a `-webkit-`prefix, and Edge has only partial support.

Comment: Thanks.. Seems like the following is working in most browser:
`    filter:grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    opacity: 0.2;`

Comment: Exactly, see browser support: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) / [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter)

Comment: That's the correct answer, and the only correct answer I guess.